# Why can't I reuse a &mut reference after passing it to a function that accepts a generic type?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Why doesn't this code compile:

```
fn use_cursor(cursor: &mut io::Cursor<&mut Vec<u8>>) {
    // do some work
}

fn take_reference(data: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    {
        let mut buf = io::Cursor::new(data);

        use_cursor(&mut buf);
    }

    data.len();
}

fn produce_data() {
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    take_reference(&mut data);
    data.len();
}
```

The error in this case is:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `*data`
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
9  |         let mut buf = io::Cursor::new(data);
   |                                       ---- value moved here
...
14 |     data.len();
   |     ^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `data` has type `&mut std::vec::Vec<u8>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

The signature of `io::Cursor::new` is such that it takes ownership of its argument. In this case, the argument is a mutable reference to a `Vec`.

```
pub fn new(inner: T) -> Cursor<T>
```

It sort of makes sense to me; because `Cursor::new` takes ownership of its argument (and not a reference) we can't use that value later on. At the same time it doesn't make sense: we essentially only pass a mutable reference and the cursor goes out of scope afterwards anyway.
In the `produce_data` function we also pass a mutable reference to `take_reference`, and it doesn't produce a error when trying to use `data` again, unlike inside `take_reference`.

I found it possible to 'reclaim' the reference by using `Cursor.into_inner()`, but it feels a bit weird to do it manually, since in normal use-cases the borrow-checker is perfectly capable of doing it itself.

Is there a nicer solution to this problem than using `.into_inner()`? Maybe there's something else I don't understand about the borrow-checker?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normally, when you pass a mutable reference to a function, the compiler implicitly performs a *reborrow*. This produces a new borrow with a shorter lifetime.

When the parameter is generic (and is not of the form `&mut T`), the compiler doesn't do this reborrowing automatically<sup>1</sup>. However, you can do it manually by dereferencing your existing mutable reference and then referencing it again:

```
fn take_reference(data: &mut Vec<u8>) {
    {
        let mut buf = io::Cursor::new(&mut *data);

        use_cursor(&mut buf);
    }

    data.len();
}
```

---

**1** — This is because the current compiler architecture only allows a chance to do a coercion if both the source and target types are known at the coercion site.