# Passing &mut directly to function accepting <R: Read> works, but not though reference variable

Tags: rust

I have this program:

```
use std::io::{self, Cursor, prelude::*};

fn file_op<R: Read>(mut reader: R) -> io::Result<()> {
    // Some file operation
    let mut buf = [0u8];
    reader.read(&mut buf)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut f = Cursor::new(vec![0xffu8]);

    // Works    
    file_op(&mut f)?;
    file_op(&mut f)?;

    let x = &mut f;

    // Does not work
    file_op(x)?;
    file_op(x)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I understand that the first portion (`// Works`) works because any `&mut T` where `T: Read` also implements `Read` (from `impl<'a, R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &'a mut R` in libstd).

However, I don't understand why the second portion (`// Does not work`) causes a use after move error. Isn't the `R` type parameter a `&mut Cursor` (which implements `Read`) in both cases? If I'm only using references, what is getting moved? The reference variable, `x`, itself?

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `x`
  --> src/main.rs:21:13
   |
20 |     file_op(x)?;
   |             - value moved here
21 |     file_op(x)?;
   |             ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `x` has type `&mut std::io::Cursor<std::vec::Vec<u8>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Interestingly, dereferencing `x` and referencing it again also works:

```
file_op(&mut *x)?;
file_op(&mut *x)?;
```

Comment: I believe the last part of your question is answered by the answers of [Why does creating a mutable reference to a dereferenced mutable reference work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45095523/155423).

Comment: I believe the rest of your question is answered by the answers of [Retaking ownership of a mutable reference passed to a function accepting a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48143889/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you! Yes, those two links answer my questions.

Comment: A better design  for your function is to mutably borrow the argument: `fn file_op<R: Read>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<()> {`. Then everything work without further ado.

Comment: Or with `impl Trait` in argument position: `fn file_op(reader: &mut impl Read) -> io::Result<()>`

Comment: I actually disagree with the two previous comments that taking a mutable reference is a *better* design.

Comment: I actually did have the function take a mutable reference before, but changed it based on the recommendation in the Rust API guidelines: https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#generic-readerwriter-functions-take-r-read-and-w-write-by-value-c-rw-value