# Borrow of moved value: how did the value move into the loop?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am getting a `borrow of moved value` error for this code:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71fc4d76df5da10fa1a95ae9f2cd79aa)

```
let mut foo = vec![1,2,3];
let bar = &mut foo;

for i in bar { // ...value moved here
    // whatever
}

bar.push(1); // borrow of moved value `bar`...
```

But how did the value of `bar` moved there? It's just a reference, right, so it should have been borrowed, not moved?

Comment: I think this is the same problem as in [Retaking ownership of a mutable reference passed to a function accepting a generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143889/retaking-ownership-of-a-mutable-reference-passed-to-a-function-accepting-a-gener). (The question is a little obscure but the answer is on point.) `for i in bar` calls `bar.into_iter()`, where `into_iter` is a trait function that takes `self`, so it doesn't trigger automatic reborrowing. You can solve it the same way, too. Does that answer your question?

Comment: `for i in bar.iter_mut()` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: @trentcl Yes, exactly! Thank you! Why didn't you post answer?

Comment: I prefer to link questions together, if possible, rather than write a new answer that is 90% the same as an existing answer. Marking this question as a duplicate may help future askers find the answer more easily, and if there are updates (let's say the auto-reborrowing algorithm changes so the original code becomes legal), the answer only needs to be updated in one place.

Comment: Another solution is to explicitly reborrow the reference: `for i in &mut *bar`

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank you, I think that may be useful in future as well.